# If $C$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R^n$, will $\{y: (x_0,y)\in C\}$ be a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

If $C$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$, will $\{y\in \Bbb R^n: (x_0,y)\in C\}$ be a closed set for any $x_0 \in \Bbb R^m$? Thanks!

The projection of $C$ into $\Bbb R^n$ might not be closed (e.g. $\{(x,y):y\ge \frac{1}{x},x\ge0\}$ projectied to x-axis is $(0,+\infty)$ which is open), but above seems to be somewhat different from projection.

Comment: what is $x_0$?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

That set the image of $C\cap (\{x_0\}\times \Bbb R^n)$ under the projection homeomorphism $\{x_0\}\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $y_n\to z $ for $y_n\in C $, then $(x_0,y_n)\to (x_0,z) $. As $C $ is closed, $(x_0,z) \in C $. So $z $ is in the set.